# Transporting failing while publishing a page

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, publishing, dxa-1.7

Is this error related to publishing transport packaging size? I am using Tridion 2013 sp1. I have below HTTPSReceiver size and attached web.config from HTTPUpload site.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just for information, have you checked your deployer running fine and the URL "http://<DeployerHost>/Deployer/HTTPUpload.aspx" is accessible from your publisher server?

Comment: @SaurabhGangwar Yes, the deployer seems working fine.